# Adding widgets to Column causes error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have code to display some text TextFields and buttons on a screen.
When I try to add the buttons I get an error at the Column.

Here is the error: Evaluation of this constant expression throws an exception.

Here is the code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          //NewAddress(),
          TextField(
            controller: _address1Controller,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              label: Text(
                'Address 1',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _address2Controller,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              label: Text(
                'Address 2',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _cityController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              label: Text(
                'City',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _stateController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              label: Text(
                'State',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _zipController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              label: Text(
                'Zip',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //SizedBox(height: 40),
          OutlinedButton.icon(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const DataScreen()));
            },
            style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue, alignment: Alignment.center),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.dataset, color: Colors.black, size: 50),
            label: const Text(
              'MINE',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

If I comment out the OutlinedButton.Icon code the error goes away and the code runs.
With all the code active (uncommented) I get the red squiggly error under Column all the way down to the end of the code.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: because `OutlinedButton.icon(` isnt use const constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the argument passed to the `onPressed` parameter of `OutlinedButton` is not constant, but the root widget (the top-most `Center` widget) is marked as `const`. This requires all sub widgets
to themselves be `const`.

Solution: Remove `const` from the top-most `Center` widget.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
    ///    ^^^^^ remove this
      child: Column(
```